# I just shifted to python and was building guess a number game but i am facing an issue

Tags: python, string

the issue is that i want to compare each element of input number and the random number guessed and then compare each element one by one and give response like print on terminal.

```
# import random
# number = random.randint(1, 10)

number = '165'
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
number_of_guesses = 0
print('okay! '+ player_name+ ' I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:')

while number_of_guesses < 5:
    guess = str(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    
    if guess[0] == number[0]:
        print('Your guess is Near')
    if guess[1] == number[1]:
        print('Your guess is Near1')
    if guess[2] == number[2]:
        print('Your guess is Near2')
    # if guess > number:
    #     print('Your guess is too high')
    # if guess == number:
    #     break
if guess == number:
    print('You guessed the number in ' + str(number_of_guesses) + ' tries!')
else:
    print('You did not guess the number, The number was ' + str(number))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```py
import random

player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
print('okay! ' + player_name + ' I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:')

random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == random_number:
        print('You guessed the number in ' + str(guess_count) + ' tries!')
        break
else:
    print('You did not guess the number, The number was ' + str(random_number))
```